# Django - order_by multiple related fields doesn't work

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying to order a qs by multiple related fields. I have a User and Credits model. Every User has a related Credits object. I want to rank/order a list of Users based on multiple fields in the Credits object:

1. credits (amount)
2. games_played_count (amount)
3. last_game_credits (amount)

Hence, if two players have an equal amount of credits the one with the highest games_played_count wins. If that is the same the one with the highest last_game_credits wins.

Models:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    username = NameField(max_length=25, unique=True)
                         
class Credits(models.Model):
    credits = models.IntegerField(default=1000)
    year = models.IntegerField(default=date.today().isocalendar()[0])
    week = models.IntegerField(default=date.today().isocalendar()[1])
    games_played_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    last_game_credits = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="credits", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('year', 'week', 'user')
```

View:

```
def get_queryset(self):

    year = self.request.query_params.get('year', None)
    week = self.request.query_params.get('week', None)

    if week and year is not None:

        prefetchCredits = Prefetch('credits', queryset=Credits.objects.filter(year=year, week=week))

        rankings = User.objects.prefetch_related(prefetchCredits) \
            .annotate(creds=Max('credits__credits'), \
                      gpcreds=Max('credits__games_played_count'), \
                      lgcreds=Max('credits__last_game_credits')) \
            .order_by('-creds', '-gpcreds', 'lgcreds')

        return rankings
```

The ordering on a single related field works but not on multiple related fields in order_by().

Endpoint call: api/rankings?year=2020&week=42

Here is what is returned:

```
[
    {
        "username": "test2",
        "credits": [
            {
                "credits": 1500,
                "year": 2020,
                "week": 42,
                "games_played_count": 1,
                "last_game_credits": 0,
                "id": 9
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "username": "test1",
        "credits": [
            {
                "credits": 1000,
                "year": 2020,
                "week": 42,
                "games_played_count": 1,
                "last_game_credits": 10,
                "id": 8
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "username": "test",
        "credits": [
            {
                "credits": 1000,
                "year": 2020,
                "week": 42,
                "games_played_count": 2,
                "last_game_credits": 15,
                "id": 7
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

The bottom obj (id 7) should be 2nd since it has more games_played_count.

As Blackeagle52 mentioned in the comments, other Credits objects (not shown in the returned data because they have other week and year) are also taken into account by .annotate and .order_by. When I deleted all other Credits objects (with other week and year), it worked. So it looks like .annotate and .order_by doesn't work on the Prefetched Credits objects.

Comment: Probably just a typo in your question, but you're missing a quotation mark after `lgcreds` there ... As far as I know what you're doing should work. What results are you seeing?

Comment: Yes, that was a typo. Edited it. Results are that it only orders on the 1st ('-creds') and not the 2nd and 3rd annotations.

Comment: That looks good to me. Not sure why you're not getting expected results. Are you sure you have proper data in database?

Comment: @Underoos, I've added the returned data

Comment: Issue lies maybe within the rendering of the data. As the returned data doesn't show the annotated items. As the credits have id 7 to 9, maybe the user ordering is determined on earlier rows not shown in the returned data?

Comment: @Blackeagle52, I've added the endpoint call. I pass the year and week parameters. With these, I Prefetch the Credit objects. So it looks like the returned data does show the annotated items. If I only use one of the annotated fields to order_by it works. Just not multiple.

Comment: @Blackeagle52, you have a point. I just deleted all the other Credits objects (other weeks and years) and now it works. Could it be that it doesn't annotate and order_by on the Prefetched Credits objects but on all Credits objects in the DB?

Comment: Yeah probably, add the following to your get_queryset method `print(rankings.query)`. See what the query is, and is it what you expected.

Comment: I can also recommend having the django debug toolbar installed in your dev env - it will let you check the queries being issued on the fly. Much easier than mucking around with printing the statements to the log :)

Comment: It simply ignores the Prefetched Credits queryset. I can fix it like this: sortedRankings = sorted(rankings, key=lambda e: (e.credits.all()[0].credits, e.credits.all()[0].games_played_count, e.credits.all()[0].last_game_credits), reverse=True). But I would prefer to have this fixed with Django since I have to use this more with deeper relations.